# Jquery datatables not displaying data in heroku python django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, heroku, datatables

I am trying to render a jquery datatable in a html form. Now, for some weird reason, I can see that I can receive the data from my API, but nothing shows up in the datatable. Interesting enough, the same code works perfectly when I am running in my local machine. But when i check the error in my heroku logs, I see that i get this error.
error logs

```
(index):254 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.success ((index):254)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

But in my local server, everything works perfectly fine.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            //We have to get all users in the system

            var jsonres=[]

            var orgid = $('#orgid').val();
            console.log('orgid',orgid)

            $.ajax({

                url: "/user/api/v1/userapi/",
                type: "get",




                success: function (json) {
                    console.log("json", json)


                    json = json.results;
                    for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
                        console.log('jsonnnn',json[i].orgid)

                        if(json[i].orgid==orgid){
                            jsonres.push(json[i])
                        }
                    }



                   console.log('jso',jsonres)
                    var data = jQuery.map(jsonres, function (el, i) {
                        /*  if(el.title.length>20){
                              el.title = el.title.substring(0,10) + '..........';
                          }*/

                        return [[el.userid, el.firstname, el.lastname, el.mobilenumber, el.email, el.isactive]];
                    });

                    $('#demotbl').DataTable({
                        "searching": true,
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "order": [[3, "desc"]],


                        "aaData": data,
                        "bPaginate": true,

                        "aoColumns": [
                            {"sTitle": "userid"},

                            {"sTitle": "firstname"},

                            {"sTitle": "lastname"},
                            {"sTitle": "mobilenumber"},
                            {"sTitle": "email"},
                            {"sTitle": "isactive"},

                        ]


                    })


                }
            })


        })


[
    {
        "userid": "test_001123456",
        "firstname": "Remy",
        "lastname": "Das",
        "email": "av20078@gmail.com",
        "mobilenumber": "082929992",
        "isactive": "yes",
        "orgid": "test_001"
    },
    {
        "userid": "test_0013456",
        "firstname": "s",
        "lastname": "sss",
        "email": "ABC@gmail.com",
        "mobilenumber": "786894651",
        "isactive": "yes",
        "orgid": "test_001"
    }
]
```

Comment: use `dataSrc:' ',` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"dataSrc": ""` and your problem solved.

Problem is because, when you are using serverside ajax, it is expecting data variable name as jsonResponse something like :

```
data: "[
    {
        "userid": "test_001123456",
        "firstname": "Remy",
        "lastname": "Das",
        "email": "av20078@gmail.com",
        "mobilenumber": "082929992",
        "isactive": "yes",
        "orgid": "test_001"
    },
    {
        "userid": "test_0013456",
        "firstname": "s",
        "lastname": "sss",
        "email": "ABC@gmail.com",
        "mobilenumber": "786894651",
        "isactive": "yes",
        "orgid": "test_001"
    }
]";
```